# How to share one catalog between multiple sites in Hybris?

Tags: e-commerce, catalog, sap-commerce-cloud

We have two sites that got multiple products in comune.
We decided to share only one catalog between these sites that contains all products without any duplication.

So far, i can see all products in both sites, but we have some products that should be shown only for one site.

Is there any solution?
We're using Hybris 5.2

The ideas we got so far are :

- Using category organization (Category for Site A , Category for Site B , Category for Shared products berween A & B)
  [image]
- Introduce a ProductSiteRelation , and a restriction.
  [image]
- Add an attribute to productModel, and extends all native Hybris classes (Controllers, Populators, Providers ...  etc) [Not that great as a solution]
- Using customer groups, the following schema explain this idea :

[image]

***Which solution is the best in our case, is there any other solution?***

Comment: In this case, You can also add solr filter

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a Search restriction under the personalization rules either through ImpEx or in HMC (you need o write the Flexible query in both cases and perform the check).